# I want to click a button and have a random image appear in a random location within my Container

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I want to be able to have a random image appear in a random location everytime you click the bottom "Try" button.
 I have been able to get it to randomize the image, but I am stumped on getting the random position to also apply to the images that get randomized.

```
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a background colour...">

<button>enter</button>

<div id="container">
    <img id="picture" src="img/img1.jpg">
</div>

<button onclick="randAll();" id = "randomButton">Try!</button>


<script>
    var bColour = document.getElementById("container");
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";

    function clickHandler()
    {
        var input = document.querySelector("#input");
        bColour.style.backgroundColor = input.value;
    }

    var pix = new Array("img/img1.jpg", "img/img2.jpg", "img/img3.jpg", "img/img4.jpg");

    function choosePic() {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * pix.length);
        document.getElementById("picture").src = pix[randomNum]

    }

    function randPos() {
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 700);


    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply some CSS like this:

```
#picture {
  position: absolute;
}

#container {
  width: 750px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Then:

```
function randPos() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 700);
  document.getElementById("picture").style.left = x + 'px';
}
```

Adjust the specific widths and heights I chose as needed.